# How to initialize JSP-Page with Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a drop down menu on my JSP page which I want to fill before the page finishes loading.

I tried something like

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    if (session.getAttribute("someArray") == null) {
        session.setAttribute("someArray", SomeEnum.values());
        doGet(request, response);
    } else { // ... // }
```

but this only fills the drop down after I submit the page. I tried it in get and post method, but either way it won't work. How can I call `Servlet.doGet()` automatically on load and set the variable if it's not set? **Or how to set the variable before the page is loaded?**

Comment: do not navigate directly to JSP pages, navigate to servlets which load the data then redirect to JSP

Comment: @ScaryWombat thank you, I set my servlet as welcome page and now it does exactly what I wanted it to. I didn't know that this was possible but great - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the servlet with the url which is loading your page (lets say `index.jsp`). Now, implement the business logic required to populate the `dropdown` options inside the `Servlet` and then do `RequestDispather.forward` and put your `index.jsp`.

Now, you have the values before the `index.jsp` has been loaded

Answer (score 1):

```
doGet(request, response);
```

This is wrong. You need to use `RequestDispatcher.forward` and mention the target resource file. If your only requirement is to make *Async* call, you should return a JSON back to the client.

```
  String json = action.execute(request, response);
  response.getWriter().write(json);
```